# URL to directly download jetty

Tags: curl, jetty, wget

The following URL from the eclipse jetty download site  does not work via wget

```
http://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/jetty/stable-9/dist/jetty-distribution-9.2.8.v20150217.zip&r=1
```

Apparently one needs to run this within a browser?

What is the way to run wget on this. The following command ends up with an xml document - and not the desired jetty jar file

```
wget -O jetty.zip http://eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/jetty/stable-9/dist/jetty-distribution-9.2.8.v20150217.zip&r=1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the artifacts, including the `jetty-distribution` can also be found on

[`central.maven.org`](http://central.maven.org/)

Just need to know the maven coordinates for the artifact you want and piece together the URL from there.

[Search for `jetty-distribution`](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cgav%7C1%7Cg%3A%22org.eclipse.jetty%22%20AND%20a%3A%22jetty-distribution%22) on [`search.maven.org`](http://search.maven.org/)

So the following artifact ...

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-distribution</artifactId>
    <version>9.2.8.v20150217</version>
</dependency>
```

against the now standard format of an artifact repository tree.

```
key:
{aid} = artifactId
{gid} = groupId
{ver} = version
{type} = type
{classifier} = classifier

http://central.maven.org/maven2/{gid}/{aid}/{ver}/{aid}-{ver}.{type}

.. and with optional {classifier} ...

http://central.maven.org/maven2/{gid}/{aid}/{ver}/{aid}-{ver}-{classifier}.{type}
```

Resulting in URL for the artifact `jetty-distribution` at version `9.2.8.v20150217` with type `tar.gz` ...

```
http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/jetty/jetty-distribution/9.2.8.v20150217/jetty-distribution-9.2.8.v20150217.tar.gz
```

*Note: the `.` in the groupId are converted to `/` when you compute your eventual URL*